# Pythonic way of writing `for my_var in my_iterable`

Tags: python

A very common pattern in python is:

```py
for something in ['an', 'iterable']:
    func(something)
```

I almost always see the iterable as a list (like in this example), but it could very well be a tuple, set, or something else. Is the list the most performant and pythonic way to do this?

Similarly, I often see the following:

```
if something_else in ['another', 'iterable']:
    func(something_else)
```

In this case, we're actually *searching* for `something_else` (note the `if` instead of `for`) which would probably be more performant if the iterable was a set. However, this might not necessarily be true for very small quantities. Is a list still the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking which data structure is more appropriate for iterating and determining object presence, or how best to write these exact scenarios of having a list of string literals in a `for` or `if` statement?

Answer (score 2):

**All of the options you've laid out for the first case (iteration) are perfectly Pythonic.** If you're going to write a `for` loop and iterate through an iterable, then it doesn't really matter what that iterable is (unless order matters, then obviously use a `tuple`, `list`, or something that maintains order and not a `set` or `dict`). That's the whole point of having an iterable as an abstraction!

**For the second case (checking a collection contains an item), I'd always recommend using a `set`.** Sure, it barely matters if your `list` is small. But code changes over time, and *usually* that change is an addition, not a subtraction. It's common for people to extend the collection to include more elements to test for. **Set up future maintainers (possibly including yourself) for success, not a performance headache.** Also, a `set` is just the right tool/abstraction for the job, since if you just want to know whether an item is in a collection, then duplicates never matter.

If you're curious about performance, never guess! Always measure. It does make a slight difference even with a small iterable:

```
In [1]: def test_if_in(x):
   ...:     if x in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
   ...:         return 'Yes'
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return 'No'
   ...:

In [2]: def test_if_in_set(x):
   ...:     if x in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:
   ...:         return 'Yes'
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return 'No'
   ...:

In [3]: %timeit test_if_in('abc')
The slowest run took 10.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 167 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit test_if_in_set('abc')
The slowest run took 11.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 116 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit test_if_in_set('one')
The slowest run took 11.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 114 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit test_if_in('one')
The slowest run took 11.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 109 ns per loop
```

Even though both are blindingly fast, the `set` version is 1.5x faster in the case where the element is not in the iterable (which makes sense, since it has to iterate through *everything* instead of doing an `O(1)` lookup like you can with a `set`). It's about the same if happens to be the first item in the iterable. It'll only matter if you're calling the function a lot. It will only get worse as the iterable grows though. The `set` starts to dominate `list`/`tuple`/non-hashed-containers very quickly.

Comment: dicts keep order now